# Keycloak version 21 , how to add Realm name and ID dynamically to access token

Tags: keycloak

How to add Realm name and ID dynamically to each access token.
I know this was possible in old Keycloak using javascript mappers, but its appear its no longer supported. Is there a way to do this without doing any custom mappers?

Comment: do you want add field to the response or treat it as the part of  content before encoded access_token

Comment: Before encode the access token

Answer (score 0):

i think you could add hardcoded mapper to specific client scope. for example add a mapper to the profile scope (make sure your client config this client scope)
[image]

the content may be look like, hardcoded you realm name in the **claim value** input  box, in this i type `master`
[image]

i create a client named test_add_realmname, then i could fetch the token and  introspect it in this client. it will be:

[image]